# how to plot 100% bar chart from a stacked chart

Tags: python, plotly, stacked-bar-chart

Hi I am trying to use plotly to create a 100% stacked bar chart in streamlit using plotly. I tried using relative but to no avail.

```
dfCategory = dfQuery.groupby(['l1_category_name','pricingPosition'])['pricingPosition'].count().reset_index(name="count")
fig = px.bar(dfCategory, x="count", y="l1_category_name", color='pricingPosition', orientation='h',
         height=400)
fig.update_layout(barmode='relative')
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the 'relative' mode in Plotly is a function to summarize positive and negative, not a display in percentages. The histogram function has the ability to stack percentages, which can also be displayed as percentages. Here is an example from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-charts-with-long-format-data).

```
import plotly.express as px

long_df = px.data.medals_long()

fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")

fig.update_layout(barmode='relative')
fig.show()
```

[image]

```
import plotly.express as px

long_df = px.data.medals_long()

fig = px.histogram(long_df, x="nation",
                   y="count", color="medal",
                   barnorm='percent', text_auto='.2f',
                   title="Long-Form Input")

fig.show()
```

[image]